# linebreak \\ doesn't work inside node

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems \libebreak doesn't work inside node. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(12,0);
\foreach \x in {0,4,8,12}
\draw (\x,0)--(\x,-0.5);
\node at (0,-0.5cm)[anchor=north]{1785\\ born in Haiti};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
As you can see, that create a problem and make my graph look terrible. Is there a way to use linebreak inside node?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an alignment, such as `align=center`. I also made your plot a bit smaller (alternatively you could make the page wider) to fit on the page, and also added `line cap=rect` to improve the finish of the ticks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw (0,0)--(12,0);
\foreach \x in {0,4,8,12}
\draw[line cap=rect] (\x,0)--(\x,-0.5);
\node at (0,-0.5cm)[anchor=north,align=center]{1785\\ born in Haiti};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]